# Let $f$ be entire such that $|f(z)|\le e^{|z|}\, \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|f(x)|\le1\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $|f(x+iy)|\le e^{|y|}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be an entire function. Suppose that $|f(z)|\le e^{|z|}\, \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|f(x)|\le1\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $|f(x+iy)|\le e^{|y|}\,\forall z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$ .

We have just recently discussed in class conformal mappings, Hadamard's 3-Lines and 3-Circles Theorems, and the Phragmen-Lindelof Theorem.

How do you solve the question above? I know for a fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is the boundary of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$, and that's about everything I know. Thanks!

Comment: Try throwing Phragmén–Lindelöf at $g(z) = f(z)\cdot e^{iz}$. (And after that, at $h(z) = f(z)\cdot e^{-iz}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phragmen-Lindeloef Theorem 
(suitable version for this question):
Suppose $f$ is analytic in a quadrant $Q$ and continuous on $\overline{Q}$.
If $|f(z)|\le 1$ on the boundary and if for some $\delta >0$, there exist constant $A$ and $B$ such that 
$$
|f(z)|\le A\exp(B|z|^{2-\delta }) \quad \text{for every } z \text{ in the quadrant,}
$$
then $|f(z)|\le 1$ throughout the quadrant.

Now consider $g(z) = f(z)\cdot e^{iz}$ in the first quadrant. Note that  $|g(x)|=|f(x)||e^{ix}|=|f(x)|\le 1$ for all $x\ge 0$ and $|g(iy)|=|f(iy)||e^{-y}|\le e^{y}\cdot e^{-y}=1$ for all $y\ge 0$.
Furthermore for every $z$ in the quadrant, $$
|g(z)|=|f(z)|\cdot e^{-y}\le |f(z)|\le e^{|z|}.$$
Therefore $g(z)$ satisfies $$
|g(z)|\le \exp(|z|^{2-\delta })$$
 with $\delta =1$ and we can conclude $|g(z)|\le 1$ throughout the quadrant, so $|f(z)|\le e^{y}$.
Similarly we have $|g(z)|\le 1$ in the second quadrant.

For the lower half plane, consider $h(z)=f(z)\cdot e^{-iz}$ instead of $g(z).$